# Linq Select Statement wont work

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity

I am getting the following error when running the following query

```
public int getPinCount(int terminalId, ref int pinnumber)
{
         using (var dbEntities = new DatabaseAccess.Schema.BMIEntityModel())
         {
              DateTime dateNow = DateTime.Now;
              return (from pins in dbEntities.PinIds
                              where pin.TerminalID.Equals((int)terminalId) 
                              && pin.PinExpireDateTime < (DateTime)dateNow
                              select pins).Count();
         }
         return 0;
}
```

> Unable to create a constant value of
>   type 'System.Object'. Only primitive
>   types ('such as Int32, String, and
>   Guid') are supported in this context.

- TerminalId = int
- PinExpireDateTime = datetime

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of EF are you using, out of curiosity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're comparing `ints` in: `pin.TerminalID.Equals((int)terminalId)` cast it before query and use `==`.

Assuming that `terminalId` is int

```
pins.TerminalID == terminalId
```

I dont understand why are u casting `dateNow` to `DateTime` it's not needed since it's already `DateTime`.

Comment: can u give me an example please ?

Comment: great thanks very much fixed it with ` from pins in dbEntities.PinIds
                                    where (pins.TerminalID ==  terminalId && pins.PinExpireDateTime < (DateTime)dateNow) `
                                    select pins

Answer (score 0):

Couple things I notice here.

1. You've used both `pins` and `pin`, but I think they're supposed to be the same identifier. This could just be a typo from copying your code into your question.
2. You've got some unnecessary explicit casts, and you're using the `Equals` method instead of just `==`. I'm not sure why you're doing that. `Equals` is overridden for Int32, so it should be the same as using the `==` operator; it *should* work fine -- but I'm not sure where else this error could come from. It's possible that LINQ to Entities isn't able to support pushing `Int32.Equals(int)` to a SQL query, even though it supports `Int32.==` just fine.

The only other possibility I can think of is that `pin.TerminalID` or `pin.PinExpireDateTime` might not be the exact datatypes you think they are, but you'll have to check that yourself.

Either way, you can at least simplify your code:

```
public int getPinCount(int terminalId, ref int pinnumber)
{
     using (var dbEntities = new DatabaseAccess.Schema.BMIEntityModel())
     {
          DateTime dateNow = DateTime.Now;
          return (from pin in dbEntities.PinIds
                  where pin.TerminalID == terminalId
                  && pin.PinExpireDateTime < dateNow
                  select pin).Count();
     }
     return 0;
}
```